# Why can't arrays be created and named dynamically in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

What rule does this violate in python?

```
for i in range(12):
    'Array'+str(1)=[]
```

To me this should make 12 empty arrays named Array0 - Array12. However, I receive 
`SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator`

What logic is this violating?

I'm thinking it might be reading this as 
`str(i)=[]`

or that 
`'Array'+ str(i) is equal to []`

Could someone confirm one or the other?

Comment: ``'Array'`` and ``'Array'+str(1)`` are strings, not a name. You cannot assign to strings. What makes you think this *should* work in the first place? What makes you think this is related to array creation?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I thought it was due to the way it was being created because the error states "cannot assign to operator" So I thought, okay, what operators am I using. Well there is a + and an =, so I figured it was one of those.

Comment: @Michal Basically, *all* of ``'Array'``, ``+`` and ``str(1)`` make invalid assignment targets. The error just can report only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Array'+str(i) is a literal string, not a variable name, so you can't assign to it. It's like trying to assign `3 = 4`.

Comment: That makes sense now. Do you know if it is possible to dynamically generate and name a bunch of lists?

Comment: @Michael This thread will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: So in Python are all variable names considered strings, but any sequence of characters surrounded by " or ' are considered string literals?

Comment: @Michael In general it's not wise to think of variable names as strings. You technically can access them as such using globals(), but there's almost never any reason to do so. Just think of them as their own thing: names.